# Counting arrays based on specific object property

Tags: php

Is it possible count arrays based on specific object property?

```
[0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 12345
            [Name] => TEST 1
            [position] => POS 1
            [2023-02-01] => 22:00 - 06:00
            [2023-02-02] => REST DAY
            [2023-02-03] => 14:00 - 22:00
            [2023-02-04] => 14:00 - 22:00
            [2023-02-05] => 14:00 - 22:00
            [2023-02-06] => 22:00 - 06:00
            [2023-02-07] => REST DAY
            [2023-02-08] => 14:00 - 22:00
            [2023-02-09] => 22:00 - 06:00
            [2023-02-10] => DAY OFF
            [2023-02-11] => 14:00 - 22:00
            [2023-02-12] =>  - 
            [2023-02-13] =>  - 
            [2023-02-14] =>  - 
            [2023-02-15] =>  - 
        )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ID] => 67890
        [Name] => TEST 2
        [position] => POS 2
        [2023-02-01] => 06:00 - 14:00
        [2023-02-02] => REST DAY
        [2023-02-03] => 06:00 - 14:00
        [2023-02-04] => 06:00 - 14:00
        [2023-02-05] => 06:00 - 14:00
        [2023-02-06] => REST DAY
        [2023-02-07] => 06:00 - 14:00
        [2023-02-08] => 06:00 - 14:00
        [2023-02-09] => 06:00 - 14:00
        [2023-02-10] => DAY OFF
        [2023-02-11] => 06:00 - 14:00
        [2023-02-12] =>  - 
        [2023-02-13] =>  - 
        [2023-02-14] =>  - 
        [2023-02-15] =>  - 
    )
```

I've been trying to use filter, but since the version is 5.3 its not applicable. I've also not been using PHP so I've been a hard time with the syntax. Note that this is a legacy system.

Comment: Yes, which property

Comment: Do you mean you want to count how many items in the array have a specific value in a particular property? Please give a proper example and clear definition of the expected output.